# WPF C# ClickOnce application not starting on another machine

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, publish

I have developed an C# WPF app. When I publish the app and double click on `WpfApplication.application` file,there is no response from machine. Application works fine on my machine. Is it because I have set target environment to **.NET Framework 4.5**, or is it something else?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using **.NET Framework 3.5 SP1**. [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606326/wpf-application-doesnt-work-on-some-machines-stopped-working-error?rq=1) for more info.

Comment: Are you saying that .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is must or any higher .net version will also work?

Comment: Not working! My Project has reference to MySQL.data.dll for MySQL connectivity. Is that causing the problem? I don't think so because in Application files I can see MySql.Data.dll.Deploy file.